# StackOverflow in BouncyCastle Gradle Project

Tags: gradle

I've importet the BouncyCastle Project with the extisting Gradle files. And I'm currently implementing a other API into BC but I'm getting a StackOverflow Error. Now I want to increase my JVM Stack. I already tried to add

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs '-Xss4m' // will add this argument to list
    // or
}
```

in the build.gradle file but nothing changed.
After that I tried to edit the Configuration and wrote to the VM Option : -Xss4m
after all nothing changed.
I searched for posts and found one who said:
I need a gradle.properties file and write org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xss4m in it.
I did that but also nothing happend.
Ifact the API that I'm implementing into BC works if I add the -Xss4m flag but it dosent work in a Gradle Project. I dont know how I to force gradle to use this flag.
I hope someone can help me to force gradle to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I finally got a solution for the problem. in the build.gradle file is a test{...} section. You only need to add jvmArgs(['-Xss4m']) in there and the Heap gets increased.